# Git Clone from another server - Fatal error

Tags: git, clone, gitlab, server

We have two servers, both have Git installed. On the other server we have a Gitlab which has a project in it. I'm trying to clone this project to another server, but I am receiving the error:

```
 fatal: does not appear to be a git repository
```

I have tried cloning in various ways.

```
git clone username@address.to.server:path/to/repo.git
git clone username@address.to.server/full/path/to/repo.git
git clone --bare username@address.to.server:path/to/repo.git
git clone ssh://username@address.to.server/full/path/to/repo.git
```

I cannot get anything to work. The server accepts my login as my username and my set up passphrase, but then it says it's not a git repository. What exactly is wrong here?

EDIT

Well, attempting to override SSL veriby via

```
GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=true git clone https://address.to.server:port/path/to/repo.git
```

actually worked in a way, but all I get with it is:

```
remote: Counting objects: 2455, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (1723/1723), done.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOFs:  12% (295/2455)
fatal: index-pack failed
```

Error logs say it's

```
[crit] 23219#0: *16 open() "/var/opt/gitlab/nginx/proxy_temp/1/00/0000000001" failed (13: Permission denied) while reading upstream
```

Comment: ...and you're **certain** that the server actually has a `.git` folder at that exact path?

Comment: I am certain as I've gone into the git-data/repositories directory and it's there. We've also cloned the project on the same server without any problems.

Comment: I'm confused: why did you do a `git init` before a `git clone`? Can you clone from GitHub and gitlab.com?

Comment: It was only one way I tried this. I've removed the .git folder already and tried other ways. I am  able to clone from Github using the https method, but I can't clone from our server using https as there are certification problems which I don't wanna solve right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well.. I managed to get this to work via the HTTPS way. I had to use

```
GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=true git clone https://address.to.server:port/path/to/repo.git
```

I got rid of the permission denied error by setting the proxy_temp folder to 0755 permissions.